# How to initialize Loggers correctly?

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

I have the following issue: I want to use the `java.util.logging.Logger`. No I found different resources [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19942521/in-java-util-logging-what-is-the-global-logger-for),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307648/change-global-setting-for-logger-instances),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315699/why-are-the-level-fine-logging-messages-not-showing), how one can modify the behavior of the logger.

Especially in the question of [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307648/change-global-setting-for-logger-instances) a (in my opinion) good structure is given to initialize the loggers according to the class name. This also allows to modify verbosity on a package based level for debugging if needed.

After a bit of digging into the problem I found out, that the global logger and the "empty" logger (with name `""`) are not the same. See also the example below.
I just created a logger `foo.Bar`, which is anchored at the empty logger instead of the logger called `foo`.
Only if I first create the logger `bar`, the logger `bar.Baz` is anchored to it correctly.

This makes the approach in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307648/change-global-setting-for-logger-instances) mainly useless as one cannot assume the parent loggers to be created before. One has to parse the class name and create loggers as needed, as far as I see.

Am I correct that I have to add some `static {...}` code to initialize the loggers in a recursive way before the own logger can be initialized?
Does this have any negative effect if multiple classes call the `Logger.getLogger(String)` method for the package loggers (resulting in multiple calls overall, e.g both `bar.Baz` and `bar.FooBaz` get the logger `bar`)?

```
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.logging.LogManager;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
public class TestLogger
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Create the logger directly
        Logger.getLogger("foo.Bar");
        // Create the logger objects step-by-step
        Logger.getLogger("bar");
        Logger.getLogger("bar.Baz");
        // Put the available loggers to output
        Enumeration<String> e = LogManager.getLogManager().getLoggerNames();
        while(e.hasMoreElements())
        {
            String s = e.nextElement();
            Logger l = Logger.getLogger(s);
            String p = (l.getParent() == null ? "none" : "'" + l.getParent().getName() + "'");
            System.out.println("'" + s + "': " + p);
        }
    }
}
```

The output of the program is

```
'bar': ''
'global': ''
'foo.bar': ''
'bar.baz': 'bar'
'': none
```

Comment: The `java.utils.Logger`s can be tricky. Although I don't fully understand what the actual question is here, a (probably) important side note: Loggers can be garbage collected. When you write `Logger.getLogger("foo").setLevel(x)` in your `main` method, and then obtain a logger with `Logger.getLogger("foo")` somewhere else, it **may** be a different instance! The logger that you obtained in the `main` may already have been garbage collected, and the second `getLogger("foo")` call will then create a new instance.

Answer (score 1):

One negative effect of having `Logger.getLogger(String)` in every class is that you won't be able to mock it (or pass a special logger) for tests.

Example: Let's say you need to test the following class C:

```
package a.b;
class C {
  private Logger logger;
  private int capacity;
  private int size;
  C(int capacity) {
    this.logger = Logger.getLogger("a.b.C");
    this.capacity = capacity;
    size = 0;
  }
  void add(int item) {
    if (size >= capacity) {
      logger.log("You already reached the capacity: " + capacity);
    }
    //...
  }
}
```

It is a requirement that add logs if the capacity is reached. Now you need to test it. It is very hard and hacky to make a test that tests this:

```
public void testCapacityReachedLogs() {
    C c = new C(2);
    c.add(1);
    c.add(2);
    // verify that c logged the exact string: "You already reached the capacity: 2"
}
```

However if you have:

```
package a.b;
class D {
  private Logger logger;
  private int capacity;
  private int size;
  D(Logger logger, int capacity) {
    this.logger = logger;
    this.capacity = capacity;
    size = 0;
  }
  void add(int item) {
    if (size >= capacity) {
      logger.log("You already reached the capacity: " + capacity);
    }
    //...
  }
}
```

Now you can mock Logger:

```
public void testCapacityReachedLogs() {
    Logger logger = getMock(Logger.class);
    D d = new D(logger, 2);
    d.add(1);
    d.add(2);
    verify(logger).log("You already reached the capacity: 2");
}
```

Note the "mock" related code doesn't necessarily follow the syntax of a framework, it's just for example.

Comment: What do you mean by "mock it"? Can you please explain a bit?

Comment: @ChristianWolf I added an example with "mock"

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thanks for explaining.